# Compare two UNIX timestamps inside a SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, unix-timestamp

I wish to fetch the next row that has `hour_status = 1` and comes after the current row (that has already been fetched and displayed). I wish to sort them after a UNIX timestamp. I've already been googling and searching trying different things, but none of which has worked so far. So how can I do this inside the SQL query?

**The wanted result is:**
`sent_date < (PREVIOUS ROWS sent_date)`

**This is the code I already have:**

```
$sql_two = "SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(sent_date) FROM user_hours WHERE hour_id = ?";
$stmt_two = $mysqli->prepare($sql_two) or die ("Feil i database<br>" . $sql_two . "<br><b>Feilmelding:</b> " . $mysqli->error);
$stmt_two->bind_param('i',$hourId);
$stmt_two->execute() or die("noe gikk galt");
$stmt_two->bind_result($db_prev_sent_date);
$stmt_two->fetch();

$sql = "SELECT hour_id FROM user_hours WHERE hour_status = 1 AND FROM_UNIXTIME(sent_date) < ? ORDER BY FROM_UNIXTIME(sent_date) desc LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql) or die ("Feil i database<br>" . $sql . "<br><b>Feilmelding:</b> " . $mysqli->error);
$stmt->bind_param('i',$db_prev_sent_date);
$stmt->execute() or die("noe gikk galt");
$stmt->bind_result($db_hour_id_next);
$stmt->fetch();
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  What is `sent_date()`?  What does the data look like?  What does your title have to do with the rest of the question?

Comment: sent_date is the name of the column where I have unixtime stored. Updated the question with some more information. My desired result is the next id with all the conditions applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you need to display the next line only and do the update separately thus your solution is perfect for the scenario you are having.

Comment: It does not take into consideration what the previous selected id had as sent_date value.

Comment: Do you want to change the hour_status for all the records at once ?

Comment: No, I want to get the next in line only. The page will show accept or deny, unchoosen is `hour_status = 2`. I want it to display the next element in line. I choose a specific date, and I want to go down from that date.

Comment: What value should I put through the `?` then. Because before this i query `sent_date` from the current `hour_id`. Should it be formated or just unixtime aswell?

Comment: Your first query should be **SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(sent_date) FROM user_hours ORDER BY FROM_UNIXTIME(sent_date) desc LIMIT 1**. You can pass the output to the second query.

Comment: I need to select the current one in order to select the one coming afterwards. Lets say I have a list of 5 items. I select nr. 3, when I press next, I want to arrive at number 4. ONLY if number 4 has `sent_date` before nr. 3 of course.